# Piece-wise contraction and fixed-point theorem

Tags: calculus, piecewise-continuity, contraction-operator

Are piece-wise contraction mappings over $[0, 1]$ also contraction mappings? and is there an associated fixed-point theorem for such functions?

More formally,
let $[0, 1]$ be the unit interval of real numbers and $[0, 1] \times [0, 1] = \bigcup_{i = 1}^N \mathbb{D}_i$ where $\mathbb{D}_i$ is the product of two sub-intervals of $[0, 1]$ and $\mathbb{D}_i \cap  \mathbb{D}_j = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq j \in [1, N]$.

Furthermore, let $f_i : [0, 1]^2 \to [0, 1], i \in [1, N]$ be contraction mappings (i.e. $d\left(f(x_1, x_2), f(y_1, y_2)\right) < d(x_1, y_1) + d(x_2, y_2)$ for some complete metric $d$ on $[0, 1]$).

Is it true that a continuous piece-wise function $g(x, y)$ (as below) is a contraction mapping?
$g(x, y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
f_1(x, y) & x,y \in \mathbb{D}_1 \\
... & \\
f_N(x, y) & x,y \in \mathbb{D}_N \\ 
\end{array}\right.$

Is it true that $g(x,y)$ have a fixed-point for each $x, y$?

Comment: In the third paragraph, do you mean $f_i : [0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]^2$?

Comment: Also, do we require $g$ to be continuous? Otherwise, the answer to both questions is no.

Comment: Although $f_i$ could be defined as you mention (this would simplify the discussion about fixed-point theorem) I intended for it to be defined as in the original question mainly since such binary functions are more common

Comment: @JosefE.Greilhuber , the question about continuity is interesting. If fi was a unary contraction mapping then since fi is Lipschitz and g is defined over a bounded domain with max distance 1 I would assume g is also Lipschitz and at least a non-expansive mapping independently if any jump-discontinuities are present (or the likes)? But for binary contraction mappings, and beyond, you're right g must be continuous. Given this additional constraint, are the statements true?

Comment: Some things are still unclear to me here. 1) Which metrics $d$ do you allow for? Most metrics are nasty (e.g. incomplete), and a contraction need not have a fixed point then. 2) In the third paragraph, do you mean $d(x_1,y_1) + d(x_2,y_2)$? 3) I understand that we are looking for fixed points of the maps $g(x,\cdot): [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ and $g(\cdot,y): [0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ for fixed $x$ and $y$, respectively. Is this correct?

Comment: @JosefE.Greilhuber Yes you're absolutely right on (1) - (3). The metric has to be constrained and for my purposes a complete metric is perfectly fine (and the fixed-point theorem may even follow some variation of Banach's fixed-point theorem).